# PHP newsletter script with [tags]

Tags: php, newsletter

I am currently working on a newsletter system in PHP. I can send quickly a lot of email messages to the different customers.

Well, I wondered how I can add `[tags]` in a textarea. I would instance the tag `[name]` add to my message and it is intended that each email message the name equals the name of the recipient.

Does anyone perhaps an idea how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is kinda wiiiide, I'm not really sure what the problem is, but this would do the trick. Obviously there is a lot of different things you can do, but start from here and work your way up.

```
function getMyNewsletter($tags){
    $newsletter = "Hello {$tags['name']}, I hope you liked your {$tags['whattheybought']}. please buy more of my stuff!";
    return $newsletter;
}

$tags = $user->getTagsFromSomewhere();
$mailbody = getMyNewsletter($tags);
yourMailer("SubjectGoesHere",$mailbody,$OtherOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch the message or template from the database and send out the email you can use something like this:

```
 $message = 'Your HTML Message or Text with your tags like [name]';

 // Replaces the tag [name] with the receiver name from the database 
 $send_message = str_replace('[name]', $fetch['Name'], $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so resolved:

page 1:

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <textarea rows="11" cols="70" name="message" id="message" placeholder="your message"></textarea>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
              <script type="text/javascript">
              <!--
                 document.write('<span id="var1" class="insert">[name]</span>, <span id="var2" class="insert">[surnaam]</span>');
              // -->
              </script>
           </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

page 2:

```
 <?php
 $message = $_POST['c_email_message'];
 $mes = $message;
 $mes = str_replace('[voornaam]',$userOb->c_user_name,$mes);                                                                                $mes = str_replace('[achternaam]',$userOb->c_user_surname,$mes);                                                                                


$html_inhoud = '';
$html_inhoud = '
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>' . htmlentities($mes) . '</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
 ';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ModifySelection () {
            var textarea = document.getElementById("myArea");
            if ('selectionStart' in textarea) {
                    // check whether some text is selected in the textarea
                if (textarea.selectionStart != textarea.selectionEnd) {
                    var newText = textarea.value.substring (0, textarea.selectionStart) + 
                        "[start]" + textarea.value.substring  (textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd) + "[end]" +
                        textarea.value.substring (textarea.selectionEnd);
                    textarea.value = newText;
                }
            }
            else {  // Internet Explorer before version 9
                    // create a range from the current selection
                var textRange = document.selection.createRange ();
                    // check whether the selection is within the textarea
                var rangeParent = textRange.parentElement ();
                if (rangeParent === textarea) {
                    textRange.text = "[start]" + textRange.text + "[end]";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="myArea" cols="30" spellcheck="false">Select some text within this field.</textarea>
    <button onclick="ModifySelection ()">Modify the current selection</button>
</body>
```